# Stored Procedure: Update column with conditional condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateStatus
    @HealthStatus NVARCHAR (MAX),
    @Risk NVARCHAR (MAX),
    @Job NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @JobStatus NVARCHAR(MAX)    
AS
BEGIN
    SET @HealthStatus = (SELECT [Health Status] FROM [tbl1])
    SET @Risk = (SELECT [Risk Level] FROM [tbl1])
    SET @Job = (SELECT [Job] FROM [tbl1])
    SET @JobStatus = (SELECT [Detail status] FROM [tbl1])
    
    IF @HealthStatus = 'Y'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [tbl1] 
            SET [Overall Status] = 'Pass' 
            WHERE [Health Status] = @HealthStatus
    END
    ELSE IF @HealthStatus = 'N'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [tbl1] 
            SET [Overall Status] = 'Fail' 
            WHERE [Health Status] = @HealthStatus
    END
    ELSE IF @Risk = 'No Risk'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [tbl1] 
            SET [Overall Status] = 'Pass and No Risk' 
            WHERE [Risk Level] = @Risk
    END
    ELSE IF @Risk = 'Not Applicable'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [tbl1] 
            SET [Overall Status] = 'Pass and No Risk'
            WHERE [Risk Level] = @Risk
    END
    IF @Risk = 'High Risk' AND (@HealthStatus = 'U' OR @HealthStatus = '')
        IF @Job = ''
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [tbl1] 
                SET [Overall Status] = @JobStatus
                WHERE [Health Status] = @HealthStatus AND [Risk Level] = @Risk AND [Job] = @Job
            END
        ELSE IF @Job = ''
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [tbl1] 
                SET [Overall Status] = 'Undefined' 
                WHERE [Health Status] = @HealthStatus AND [Risk Level] = @Risk AND [Job] = @Job
            END
END
GO
```

I wrote a stored procedure to update overall status based on the input from another columns in the same table which I will execute within the SQL Server. However, I came across:

> Procedure or function 'UpdateStatus' expects parameter '@HealthStatus', which was not supplied.

I had assigned the value to the parameter by using SELECT function. I'm new to stored procedure and I'm not sure where am I doing wrong here.

I only wrote the calling code within sql server

```
EXEC UpdateStatus
```

Comment: You need to show us the calling code, thats where the error is.

Comment: You need to pass the parameters in unless they have defaults!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you don't need parameters at all if you don't plan to use them.
you already created variables. Parameters are for passing values in during exec

```
Exec dbo.SomeProc @param1 = 'testvalue'
```

Also your procedure relies on tbl1 only having 1 row in it.

```
SET @HealthStatus = (SELECT [Health Status] FROM [tbl1])
```

If the table has more than 1 row then this will just get you the value in the last row.
Your update statements could affect many rows

I think what you need is something like this..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateStatus 
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.tbl1
    SET [Overall Status] = CASE WHEN [Health Status] = 'Y' AND ([Risk Level] = 'No Risk' OR [Risk Level] = 'Not Applicable') THEN 'Pass and No Risk' 
                                WHEN ([Health Status] = 'U' OR [Health Status] = '') AND [Risk Level] 'High Risk' THEN 'Pass and No Risk' 
                                ...
                            END
                            
END
GO
```

you could even abandon the Overall Status column and just have it as computed

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.tbl1WithStatus 
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *,  -- don't really use select *,  use column names
            CASE WHEN [Health Status] = 'Y' AND ([Risk Level] = 'No Risk' OR [Risk Level] = 'Not Applicable') THEN 'Pass and No Risk' 
                 WHEN ([Health Status] = 'U' OR [Health Status] = '') AND [Risk Level] 'High Risk' THEN 'Pass and No Risk' 
                 ...
                 END AS [Overall Status]
    FROM dbo.tbl1
                            
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! yours worked the best and simpler than my original code.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the parameters without default values. So, the procedure is expecting the parameters. If you don't specify values for parameters then the default values will be taken.

In the below code, default values will be taken for the parameters.

```sql
EXEC UpdateStatus
```

Also, always define procedures with the schema name. Also, handle the default values internally in the procedure. If values are not passed, then the default value is taken. If default value NULL is taken, handle it accordingly in the code.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateStatus
    @HealthStatus NVARCHAR (MAX) = NULL ,
    @Risk NVARCHAR (MAX) = NULL,
    @Job NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @JobStatus NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL   
BEGIN

IF @HealthStatus IS NULL 
BEGIN
SET @HealthStatus = (SELECT [Health Status] FROM [tbl1])
END 

IF @Risk IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @Risk = (SELECT [Risk Level] FROM [tbl1])
END 


IF @Job  IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @Job = (SELECT [Job] FROM [tbl1])
END 

IF @JobStatus IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @JobStatus = (SELECT [Detail status] FROM [tbl1])
END 

.
.
.
```